# FadeOut/FadeIn jQuery jump

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Any thoughts on why this sometimes make the page jump. It appears like fadeOut is actually removing the height of the element #main. Its height is declared in CSS. Tested in FireFox 20

```
$('.active').click(function(){
    $('#main').fadeOut(1100, function() {
        $(this).load('blank.html', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(1100);
        });
    });
    return false;
});

<div id="main" style="margin-bottom:30px;overflow:hidden">
    <div class="slider nivoSlider">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="4.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

<li><a href="blank.html" class="active">Projects (a)</a></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jump"?

Comment: Should I use animate instead to set opacity to 0?

Comment: The footer jumps to the top of the page then back down again when fadeIn begins.

Comment: by jump, i think he means that the parent's div is changing size when #main fades out (because it is set to display:none)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fadeIn` and `fadeOut` will set the display to none after it's finished fading out the content, which makes the element dissapear, and the flow on the page is interrupted. Try just animating the opacity instead:

```
$('.active').click(function(){
    $('#main').animate({opacity: 0}, 1100, function() {
        $(this).load('blank.html', function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1100);
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`fadeOut` also does `hide`, which is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'none')`

`dislay: none`, hides the element (and its dimensions) completely from layout.

It is probably safer to put the `opacity` to 0, if you are having problems with this

Answer (score 1):

You could also animate the height and the padding to `0px` like this:

```
$('#main').animate({height:'0px', padding:'0px'}, {duration: 1100});
```

With this method the site does not jump because the height get slowly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your HTML, but I imagine you have the active class on an anchor (`<a></a>`).  Do the following:

```
$('.active').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#main').fadeOut(1100, function() {
           $(this).load('blank.html', function() {
               $(this).fadeIn(1100);
           });
       });
       return false;
});
```

Comment: No need for `return false;` if you use `event.preventDefault();` unless it's specific for some unknown reasons